# Adding the numeric sum of arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on this homework assignment and arrays are confusing the heck out of me. I know its a simple solution but cant figure it out. So if figured id post it on here to see if anyone can help with it. I'm not looking for the direct answer but just something to point me in the right direction. I know you guys hate helping with homework, but this is driving me nuts. I know its one minor thing i need to change but cant figure out what it is. In any case here it is

The assignment is in Visual Basic (windows forms application)

The objective is to create a project named FindSumArray that calculates the sum of 10 arbitrary integers. Only the sum needs to appear on the form. The numbers used to calculate the sum do not need to appear. You may use an array initializer to assign values to the array, the program should use an array to store the integers and a loop to find the sum.  The only control needed in this assignment is an output label to display the result.

Here is the code I have for it. I set it up so when the form loads it displays the sum by use of a label. but for some reason its not adding the elements.
When I run it I get 2 showing up in the form. but the sum needs to be
55(by adding each number in the array)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    Dim element As Integer
    Dim total As Integer

    For Each element In numbers
        total = element + element
    Next element
    lblSum.Text = total.ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `total = element + element` I think you meant `total = total + element`... I'm not a vb.net guy so I'll leave this as a comment (I can't tell if there are other errors in your code), but that might be enough to get things working again.

Comment: yup that worked.. I knew it was some stupid error like that. thanks.

Comment: Oh, cool! I'll post that as an answer, then, if you don't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = element + element
```

I think you meant

```
total = total + element
```

so your loop keeps adding to the existing total instead of constantly resetting it.